# New Rows are added to datagrid automatically

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a table called UnitRelations in a database called ERP_Lite in SQL Server. The structure of this table is as follows:

```
Column Name        |  Data Type     |     Allow Nulls
-------------------+----------------+----------------
UnitRelationID     |  int           |     No            [Primary Key]
FirstUnitID        |  int           |     No            [Foreign Key - Units]
FirstUnitQuantity  |  float         |     No
SecondUnitID       |  int           |     No            [Foreign Key - Units]
SecondUnitQuantity |  float         |     No
ItemID             |  int           |     Yes           [Foreign Key - Items]
```

I have used `entity framewwork`. So while creating `ADO.Net Entity Data Model (.edmx)` name of the `UnitRelations` is singularized to `UnitRelation`.

Now in my view-model file -- ItemsViewModel.cs

```
public class ItemsViewModel : MainViewModel
{
    public ItemsViewModel()
    {
        using(Entities db = new Entities())
        {
            Units = (from m in db.Units
                     select m).ToList();
        }

        UnitRelations = new List<UnitRelation>();
    }

    private IEnumerable<Unit> _units;
    public IEnumerable<Unit> Units
    {
        get
        {
            return _units;
        }
        set
        {
            _units = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Units");
        }
    }

    private List<UnitRelation> _unitRelations;
    public List<UnitRelation> UnitRelations
    {
        get
        {
            return _unitRelations;
        }
        set
        {
            _unitRelations = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("UnitRelations");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Items.xaml file:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding UnitRelations}"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Something" Width="*">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="First Unit" />
                    <ComboBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Units, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Page}}}">
                        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Width="100" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Symbol}" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ComboBox>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="Second Unit" />
                    <ComboBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Units, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Page}}}">
                        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Width="100" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Symbol}" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ComboBox>

                        <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding FirstUnitQuantity}"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" />
                        <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding SecondUnitQuantity}"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Here are the screen-shots of my Output and Problems:

(1) Initially

[image]

(2) When I select Items in the ComboBox

[image]

(3) After selecting Items from Combobox when I Click on DataGrid's empty area

[image]

(4) When I click on any control outside DataGrid e.g. TextBox (A new row at the top of the datagrid is added automatically)

[Note: If I do not click on datagrid's empty area then step 3 is skipped and the problem does not exist anymore.]

[image]

(5) When I double Click on last row of datagrid.

[image]

(6) When I click on any other row a new row is again added and this process adds new rows continuously as many times as I click on any row of datagrid.

[image]

**Finally, I would like to know the reason of new row addition to datagrid and stop my app to add those rows.**

Comment: Your `DataGrid.ItemsSource` property is data bound to the `UnitRelations` collection, so if new rows are appearing in the `DataGrid`, then *you must be adding items into the `UnitRelations` collection* somewhere... *that's* where your problem is.

Comment: No, I have just started to create this project and I am not adding any items to the `UnitRelations` anywhere in my whole project.

Comment: I can't figure out the problem but I have got a solution. I used ListBox instead of DataGrid and now it works fine.

Comment: Yes, strange but true.